# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id message= This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I 'm trying to connect to Chrome Version 76 and chromedriver 76 as well!

I have tried all of the version  of the chromedriver but seems that no one is working

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'KASTIOT', ip: '192.168.0.104', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 85ef5c2570c97d5b10f13f818d4096f4
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:915)
  at stepdefs.websitesteps.ZitiCard.goToWebsite(ZitiCard.java:30)
  at ✽.Given Go to website(C:/Users/lotib/Desktop/recyclego 2/src/test/java/website/ZitiCard.feature:5)
```

To make sure that it goes to the link I wrote down and follow the Scenarios??

Help would be great :)

Comment: lotiblakaj123@gmail.com Is my email if you want more explanations !

Comment: Do you have Chrome installed in the default directory?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. simply passing `--disable-dev-shm-usage` to chrome did the trick.

> ## Chrome crashes
>
> Chrome uses /dev/shm for runtime data which is 64MB by default under Docker. If this is > not sufficient then this can cause Chrome to crash. Possible workarounds:
>
> - Increase the size of /dev/shm
> - Mount /dev/shm to the host's
> - Start Chrome with the flag --disable-dev-shm-usage

source: https://github.com/markhobson/docker-maven-chrome#chrome-crashes

Answer (score 5):

NoSuchSessionExpection happens when you try to perform any actions after webdriver.quit().
Make sure you are not calling any command after webdriver.quit().

Comment: Thanks i have fix it ,There was a problem with Drivers Versions and this also i added for the driver to quit after it is done, because it just  block the por.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'KASTIOT', ip: '192.168.0.104', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=74.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=74.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

- Presumably you are using *chrome= 75.0* or *chrome= 76.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome 75**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.3.1* of *2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000* which is almost **2** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_111** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u111* , *Selenium Client v3.3.1* , *ChromeDriver v74.0* and the *Chrome Browser v75.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure the following:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u212](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.